# _TABLE_SUFFIX missing?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use this code in BigQuery taking the data obviously form GA and it seems that has a problem with the _TABLE_SUFFIX . The error says ' Error: Unrecognized name: _TABLE_SUFFIX at [12:3]' Could you help to figure it out why is that?

```
SELECT
fullVisitorId,
visitId,
visitNumber,
hits.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath
FROM
`110042578.ga_sessions_intraday_20190228`,
UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX = '20190228'
AND
hits.type="PAGE"
ORDER BY
fullVisitorId,
visitId,
visitNumber,
hitNumber
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the wildcard * in your table reference, there is no field _table_suffix.
Try

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  visitNumber,
  hits.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
  hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath
FROM
  `110042578.ga_sessions_intraday_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20190228'
  AND
  hits.type="PAGE"
ORDER BY
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  visitNumber,
  hitNumber
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanx for help. Do you have an idea how I could compose a SQL query to find the sequence of events in bigquery?

Comment: Sure. I'd recommend to create a new question for that.